# Internet explorer versions >8 compatibility issues, not working with meta code too

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have of compatibility issue of my website working on internet explorer versions 9 and above only. I searched the net but I got no answer. I got something close, if I add this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

The website works on Internet version 8 and below, but not on 9 and above. And if i remove it, it goes the other way round (works on internet versions 9 & above but not 8 & below).

**html:**

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="top nav css.css">
    <title>Universal Stationary</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>

    <div class=transbox>  

        <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5" cols="2" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr align="center">
                <td height="15%"><img src="banner.gif" width="90%"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr height="1%">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="example">
                        <ul id="navigationbar">
                            <li><a href="homepage/home.html" target="mainframe">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="productspage.html" target="mainframe">Products</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="penbrand/penbrands.html" target="mainframe">Pens</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="pencilbrand/pencilbrand.html" target="mainframe">Pencils</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="staplerbrands/staplerbrand.html" target="mainframe">Staplers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="sharpenerbrand/sharpenerbrand.html" target="mainframe">Sharpeners</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="eraserbrand/eraserbrand.html" target="mainframe">Erasers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="photocopypaperbrands/photocopypaperbrand.html" target="mainframe">Photocopy Papers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="cartridgebrand/cartridgebrand.html" target="mainframe">Cartridges</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="comparepage/comparepage.html" target="mainframe">Compare</a></li>
                            <li><a href="dealofthemonthpage/dealofthemonthpage.html" target="mainframe">Free Monthly Coupons</a></li>
                            <li><a href="aboutuspage/aboutus.html" target="mainframe">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contactuspage/contactus.html" target="mainframe">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="feedbackpage/feedback.html" target="mainframe">Feedback</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2" height="*">
                    <iframe src="homepage/home.html" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" name="mainframe"></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <br>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2" height="11%"><p align="left">Our Brands:</p>
                    <marquee direction="left" behavior="alternate">
                        <img src="brands/3m_logo_19.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/bic_18.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/canon_logo_21.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/casio_27.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/citizen_74.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/double-a-logo+slogan_30.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/epson_64.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/hp_logo_39.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/logo_paperone_putih_38.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/max-logo_37.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/pelikan_41.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <img src="brands/stz_51.jpg"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    </marquee>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div> 

</center>
</body>


</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-image:url(background.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}

div.transbox{
    width:inherit;
    height:1450px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:70px;
    margin-right:70px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:rgba(230,230,255,.9);
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    display: table;
}

iframe{
    min-height:1000px !important;   
}
```

**TOP NAVIGATION MENU CSS:**

```
/* main styles */
#navigationbar {
    display:table;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background:#00C;

    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}
#navigationbar li {
    margin-left:26px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
}
#navigationbar a {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#e7e5e5;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:5px 15px;
    clear:both;
    font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;

    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    text-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
}

/* onselect menu element */
#navigationbar .current a, #navigationbar li:hover > a {
    background:#09F;
    color:#000;
    border-top:1px solid #f8f8f8;

    box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .7);
    text-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
}

/* sub-levels */
#navigationbar ul li:hover a, #navigationbar li:hover li a {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    color:#000;
}
#navigationbar ul li a:hover {
    background:#00C;
    color:#fff;

    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    text-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
}

#navigationbar ul li:first-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
}
#navigationbar ul li:last-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}

/* drop-down menu */
#navigationbar li:hover > ul {
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}
#navigationbar ul {
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    padding:0;
    width:175px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#09F;
    border:1px solid #7788aa;
    display: table; 
    margin: 0 auto;

    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .5);

    -moz-transition:opacity .25s linear, visibility .1s linear .1s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .25s linear, visibility .1s linear .1s;
    -o-transition:opacity .25s linear, visibility .1s linear .1s;
    transition:opacity .25s linear, visibility .1s linear .1s;
}
#navigationbar ul li {
    float:none;
    margin:0;
}
#navigationbar ul a {
    font-weight:normal;
    text-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
    font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
}
#navigationbar ul ul {
    left:160px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Two problems:

1. Compatibility issues on IE
2. The top navigation drop-down list doesn't work on IE

Comment: maybe something to do with unescaped spaces in the links to css?

Comment: Your HTML does not pass [W3C validation](http://validator.w3.org).  Deprecated tags & attributes, no doctype, unescaped spaces in the href URL for the CSS includes... generally invalid HTML.  Explorer wants valid HTML.

Comment: Are you seriously using a `<marquee>` tag?

Comment: Hey where is your `!DOCTYPE` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The website works on Internet version 8 and below, but not on 9 and
>   above. And if i remove it, it goes the other way round (works on
>   internet versions 9 & above but not 8 & below).

If that's the case, why don't you put the meta-tag in a conditional tag. That way it is only displayed when the browser is a version less than IE 9.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<![endif]-->
```

But take note! From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/en-en/library/cc817574.aspx):

> It is recommended that Web developers restrict their use of Edge mode
>   to test pages and other non-production uses because of the possible
>   unexpected results of rendering page content in future versions of
>   Windows Internet Explorer.

However, it seems to me that your website defaults to compatibility/quirks mode, which causes some malfunction. For instance, you didn't write any doctype. That's something you should fix. More importantly though is your HTML. That's some bad mark-up you have there. Don't use tables for lay-out purposes, only for tabular data. Don't use deprecated tags (`<center>`).

It seems that you used a HTML and CSS generator for this. Don't do that, it will only write bad/not cross-browser friendly code which leads to problems like this one.

Comment: seems a bit crude, and with no explanation about why it's not working with the meta tag in <IE8, but it should solve it. +1

Comment: Deprecated tags & attributes, no `doctype`, unescaped spaces in the href URL for the CSS includes, generally invalid HTML...

Comment: @Sparky I just added that, exactly. :)

Comment: Usage of `table` tags for layout is bad practice, but not the cause of his problems.

Comment: @Sparky I never said it was. I merely stated that he should reconsider the code he used, because it has multiple errors in it. I think the cause of his problem is the absence of a doctype.

Comment: That does not make my comment any less accurate.  Using `table` tags for layout is simply bad practice, not an "error"... the browser doesn't care what's inside the `table` as long as it's valid HTML.